# Invisible text in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qt5, ubuntu-16.04

I am learning Qt and running examples from Qt SDK 5.9.1. I run the code below and write inside QTextEdit but no text appears. Cursor moves as I write but no text is shown. Window title text is shown. I added `addApplicationFont` and `setFont` calls below I found from web to the sample but it didn't help.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("://Ubuntu-R.ttf");
    app.setFont(QFont("Ubuntu", 11, QFont::Normal, false));

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and run following commands on bash to make executable:

```
qmake -makefile
make
./part1
```

I want the app to use the default Ubuntu system font. I learned that Qt uses fontconfig for fonts but I don't know how to trace the issue.

**Edit**

I thought `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("://Ubuntu-R.ttf")` call referenced system font but instead it is referencing font app resource file. I don't have resource file so obviously it won't work.

.pro file is below(unmodified sample file):

```
QT += widgets
SOURCES = main.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/tutorials/gettingStarted/gsQt/part1
INSTALLS += target
```

I tried to get system font using QFontDatabase but it didn't work:

```
app.setFont(QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::GeneralFont));
```

This doesn't do anything with any of enum values including `QFontDatabase::GeneralFont`

```
QFontDatabase database;
QStringList fam = database.families();
```

`fam` size is zero.

I will try to use embedded font next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason of the problem but the reason was not configuring fontconfig dependency properly before building qt. I solved it by reconfiguring and recompiling qt again. You can find more details at qt [forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82789/invisible-text-in-qtextedit/25).